# Working on Peano Axioms in Agda and hit a bit of a sticking point

Tags: haskell, axiom, agda

```
PA6 : ∀{m n} -> m ≡ n -> n ≡ m
```

is the axiom I am trying to solve and support, I've tried using a cong (from the core library) but am having troubles with the cong constructor

```
PA6 = cong
```

gets me nowhere, I know for cong I am required to supply a refl for equality and a type, but I'm, not sure what type I'm supposed to supply. Ideas?

This is for a small assignment at University, so I'd rather someone demonstrate what I've missed rather than write the acutual answer, but I'd appreciate any degree of support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the nature of the system that I had created, I had to realise I had two equivalences and thus needed to use the equivalence method refl

Thus to satisfy my type signature agda accepted: `PA6 refl = refl`

hope that helps

Comment: Please post a bit more about the solution so it can help others who have a similar problem (at least your definition of ℕ and _≡_, or the lib version and module name if they are from a library). Upvote will follow :)

Answer (score 7):

Your PA6 says that ≡ is *symmetric.*

This can be found in the standard library from the Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality module.

```
sym : ∀ {a} {A : Set a} {x y : A} → x ≡ y → y ≡ x
sym refl = refl
```

(This question is pretty old, but I'm posting for the benefit of future readers that stumble upon it.)